# can a character be pointed by a pointer in c

Tags: c, string, pointers, character

Though we can use  a pointer to point an array of characters i.e. strings but can a single character be pointed by a pointer in C?
E.g. Is this code valid?

```
 char *p='a';
```

Comment: yes to your first question, no to the second.

Comment: Did you try compiling your code? The compiler should give you warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course you can use a pointer to point to a single character, but you can't go about it in the way that you propose.

```
char* p = 'a';
```

is just as incorrect as

```
int* q = 5;
```

You're assigning a character value to a pointer. Remember that a pointer is a memory address, so `char* p = 'a';`  means that you think that there's a `char` in the memory address `'a'`. That's probably not what you want, and conceptually it makes no sense.

You can accomplish what you want like this:

```
char c = 'a';
char* p = &c;
```

Answer (score -1):

`char *p=&a;` is valid, where a is a single character.  It's a `char *` that points to a constant of a single character.
[Corrected per @RedAlert's comment]

Comment: nope. a correct syntax would be something like `char c = 'a'; char *p = &a;`

Comment: @RedAlert is correct, my mistake.  You can create a pointer to a single character, but the syntax requires referring to the address of a, as said.

Comment: i made a mistake in my comment, should be `&c`. The statement `char *p=&a;` is only valid if a is a `char`.

Comment: My answer is nevertheless corrected, as I used 'a' to mean a single character

Comment: there is nothing in your answer that mentions  or defines `a` as a char.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64980/discussion-between-brycem-and-red-alert).